# Getting a error when i try to fin overlap

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting an error when i try to find out if the computer is available and not rented out to someone else. I hope someone know what is wrong.

here is the code:

```
public boolean checkDate(int computerID, String from, String to) {

    String SQLString = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE computerID= "+ computerID + " AND to > " + from + " AND from < " + to+ "";
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        PreparedStatement query = DB.open().prepareStatement(SQLString);
        rs = query.executeQuery();
        rs.next();

        int rowCount = rs.getRow();

        if (rowCount < 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        DB.close();
    }
    return false;

}
```

The error message is this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:56 AND start < 13:34:56' at line 1
```

UPDATED!

I have now changed the code so it dont give an error. But now it always return true :S

Here is the updated code:

```
public boolean checkDate(int computerID, String from, String to) {

    String SQLString = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE computerID= "+ computerID + " AND slut > '" + from + "' AND start < '" + to+ "'";
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        PreparedStatement query = DB.open().prepareStatement(SQLString);
        rs = query.executeQuery();
        rs.next();

        int rowCount = rs.getRow();

        if (rowCount < 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        DB.close();
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: did you try enclosing from and to in single quotes? Sharing stack trace will bring help much faster :)

Comment: You are using a `PreparedStatement` which is good but not leveraging it completely and forming your own SQL statement which is prone to errors and SQL Injection. You should get your `from` and `to` as `java.util.Date` or joda `DateTime` values and use the setter methods on the prepared statement to set parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `from` and `to` are time-stamps. Enclosing them in single quotes should fix this.

Moreover, using String to represent timestamps in code is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields corresponding to 'from' and 'to' in your database are of datetime type this query will always return zero or for your case true because the conversion from string to datetime is illegal. Try converting 'from' and 'to' to date type. See examples [click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)